# Not able to view and download the salesforce record, have used lwc component but when we click on view and download nothing is coming

Tags: lightning-web-components

HTML

```html
<template>
    <div class="myColor">
    <lightning-card title="Print Risk Data" icon-name="standard:channel_program_history">
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="4" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="4"
            padding="around-small">
            
            <lightning-input 
            name="input1" 
            label="Enter Start Date" 
            type="date" onchange={changeInStartDate}
            ></lightning-input> 
        
            
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="4" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="4"
            padding="around-small">
            
            <lightning-input 
            name="input1" 
            label="Enter End Date" 
            type="date" onchange={changeInEndDate}
            > </lightning-input>
            
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="4" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="4"
        padding="around-small">
       <br/>
            <lightning-button variant="brand"  label="Search"  onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
        </lightning-card>
        </div>
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={dataFetchVal}
                columns={columns}
                hide-chechbox-column="true"
                show-row-number-column="true">
        </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

JS

```js
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import searchDataFromRisk from '@salesforce/apex/FetchDataForInherentRisk.searchDataFromRisk';
import getContentVersion from '@salesforce/apex/FetchDataForInherentRisk.getContentVersion';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'Start Date', fieldName: 'Risk_Start_Date__c' },
    { label: 'End Date', fieldName: 'Risk_End_Date__c'},
    { label: 'Risk Name', fieldName: 'RiskName__c'},
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status__c'},
    {
        label: 'View',
        type: 'button',
        initialWidth: 135,
        typeAttributes: { label: 'View File', name: 'view_file', title: 'Click to View Details' }
    },
    {
        label: 'Download',
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 135,
        typeAttributes: { iconName: 'utility:download', name: 'download_file', title: 'Click to download' }
    }
];
export default class PrintRiskData extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    dataFetchVal = [];
    columns = columns;
    @track startDateVal;
    @track endDateVal;
    changeInStartDate(event){
        this.startDateVal=event.detail.value;
        console.log('this.startDateVal'+this.startDateVal);
    }
    changeInEndDate(event){
        this.endDateVal=event.detail.value;
        console.log('this.endDateVal'+this.endDateVal);
    }
    handleClick(){
        console.log('this.startDateVal'+this.startDateVal);
        console.log('this.endDateVal'+this.endDateVal);
        searchDataFromRisk({startDatePassVal:this.startDateVal,endDatePassVal:this.endDateVal}).then(data=>{
        this.dataFetchVal=data;
        console.log('this.dataFetchVal'+JSON.stringify(this.dataFetchVal));
        
        
        })
    }
    handleRowAction(event) {
        var action = event.detail.action;
        var row = event.detail.row;
        switch (action.name) {
            case 'view_file':
                this.navigateToFiles(row.Id);
                break;
            case 'download_file':
                this.downloadFile(row.Id);
                break;
            default:
                this.navigateToFiles(row.Id);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    navigateToFiles(id) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'filePreview'
            },
            state: {
                recordIds: id
            }
        });
    }
    
    downloadFile(id) {
        getContentVersion({ docId: id })
            .then((versionId) => window.open(`/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/${versionId}`))
            .catch((error) => console.error('ERROR => ', error));
    }
}
```

Apex

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
Public static List<Risk__c> searchDataFromRisk(date startDatePassVal, date endDatePassVal){
    List<Risk__c> searchData = [select id,Name,Risk_Start_Date__c,Risk_End_Date__c,Status__c,RiskName__c,Region__c
                                from Risk__c
                                where (Risk_Start_Date__c >= :startDatePassVal AND Risk_End_Date__c <= :endDatePassVal)
                                ORDER BY Risk_Start_Date__c];
    return searchData;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static string getContentVersion(Id docId){
    return [ SELECT Id, IsLatest, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId=:docId AND isLatest=true LIMIT 1].Id;
}
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't attach the row action handler to the datatable, so `handleRowAction` never run. Just add the [`onrowaction`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) attribute should fix it:

```html
<lightning-datatable
    key-field="Id"
    data={dataFetchVal}
    columns={columns}
    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
    hide-chechbox-column="true"
    show-row-number-column="true">
</lightning-datatable>
```

By the way, in JS you should prefer [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) over `var`.
Moreover there is no need to *track* `startDateVal` or `endDateVal`.